# How to find out the dependencies of stored procedure using sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want a script which will show the dependencies of stored procedure in database. Actually when we manually do view dependency it will take a lot of time I have more than 500 stored procedures. So, I wanted to know that these stored procedures are used in database or not so that I can remove the useless stored procedure.

`sp_depends` is not showing all results because I want all objects that depends on this stored procedure 'usp_Constant_Get_Pvt' and objects on which it depends.

```
EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'usp_Constant_Get_Pvt'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use this script in a similar situation (don't forget to use the schema name):

```
--
DECLARE
    @sp nvarchar(100)
SET @sp = N'dbo.usp_Constant_Get_Pvt'

-- Objects that depends on [@sp]
SELECT 
    referencing_schema_name, 
    referencing_entity_name
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(@sp, 'OBJECT')

-- Objects on which [@sp] depends
SELECT 
    referenced_schema_name, 
    referenced_entity_name
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(@sp, 'OBJECT')

SELECT
    referenced_schema_name, 
    referenced_entity_name
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(@sp)
```

Answer (score 6):

Below code will be using Expression Dependencies to find out the dependencies on a stored procedure. The advantage of expression dependencies are, they can find cross database dependencies also. But, if there is dynamic SQL, we have to go for searching in the `sql_modules`.

[Reference URL](https://www.sqlrx.com/using-sys-sql_expression_dependencies-as-a-single-source-to-find-referenced-and-referencing-objects/)

#### Objects referencing Stored procedure

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME ( referencing_id ) AS referencing_schema_name,  
    OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name,   
    o.type_desc AS referencing_desciption,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referencing_minor_id,   
    referencing_class_desc, referenced_class_desc,  
    referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name,  
    referenced_entity_name,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referenced_column_name,  
    is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous  
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed  
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id  
WHERE referenced_id = OBJECT_ID(N'SchemaName.StoredProcedureName');  
GO
```

#### Objects referenced in the Stored Procedure

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name,   
    o.type_desc AS referencing_desciption,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referencing_minor_id,   
    referencing_class_desc,  
    referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name,  
    referenced_entity_name,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referenced_column_name,  
    is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous  
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed  
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id  
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'SchemaName.StoredProcedureName');  
GO
```

Comment: Can this be made universal? i.e, if my sproc is in Database X, and I execute this script in Database Y, I get no results. Can this be somehow modified to bring results from other databases?

Comment: you have to run it against each database as mentioned in the SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22733306/634935

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Following Query

```
SELECT 
    referencing_schema_name, 
    referencing_entity_name,
    referencing_id, 
    referencing_class_desc, 
    is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('YourObject', 'OBJECT');
```

Please refer [This link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/) for more detailed information

Comment: i have already tried this but it is giving me empty table but there are dependencies when i click view dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following SQL Server script:**

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, referencing_class,  referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(N'usp_Constant_Get_Pvt' , 'OBJECT')
```