# How to find all the functions and stored procedures called in a stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to know all the functions and stored procedures called in a stored procedure in sql server.

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why the irrelevant tags? As for finding all the dependencies of a stored procedure, just right click on the procedure and click `View Dependencies`

Comment: SQL Server Profiler shoud help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out the dependencies of stored procedure using sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070058/how-to-find-out-the-dependencies-of-stored-procedure-using-sql)

Comment: Please provide some proper information that you want achieve and problems you faced. :)

Answer (score 1):

This shows all objects referenced by the given procedure:

```
select  isnull(re.referenced_schema_name, 'dbo') referenced_schema_name, 
        referenced_entity_name as referenced_object_name,
        o.type_desc referenced_object_type
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.YourProcedureName', 'OBJECT') re
inner join sys.objects o on (o.object_id = re.referenced_id)
                         or (o.name = re.referenced_entity_name and schema_name(o.schema_id) = isnull(referenced_schema_name, 'dbo'))
where re.referenced_database_name is null 
and o.type_desc in (
    'SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION', 
    'SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION', 
    'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION',
    'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE', 
    'SQL_TRIGGER',
    'CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTION',
    'CLR_STORED_PROCEDURE',
    'CLR_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION',
    'CLR_TRIGGER'
)
```

but it shows only procedure in the same database and same server and it does not show if a procedure or function is called inside a dynamic sql query.