# MS SQL Server get db_name() for referenced object from sys.sql_dependencies

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating sp to check obsolete columns used in given db's objects and using `sys.sql_dependencies`. I've checked all I could and don't see where I can get `db_name` for column I'm searching for. I just want to make sure that it's correct one, in code this column prefixed by `db_name.dbo.TableName` so I hopek it's stored somewhere, but not in  `dependencies` table I think.
I know that **SYS** tables are db_name specific, so maybe in this case it not available? so I can get false hit on same table.column but from different db.

This is my sample code, in this case I search dbNameAAA.table.column (or list of them) in another database's objects (sp,udf,views,triggers,etc..)

```
SELECT  TOP 10
'?????'  db,  -- for ro.name, c.name referenced
ro.name  Tbl,  c.name Col,     ' -->' [_Found in_],
(SELECT  DB_NAME())  db_current,
o.name ObjName,  o.object_id,   o.type_desc ObjType, SCHEMA_NAME(ro.schema_id) Sch_Name
FROM sys.sql_dependencies AS d
  INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS o         ON o.object_id = d.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS ro        ON ro.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
  INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS c         ON c.object_id = ro.object_id AND c.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id
WHERE 1=1  
    and (c.name = 'Cust_ID')
    AND o.type_desc LIKE '%procedure%'
```

**Update** and this c'be solution:
This has all info even server name for ref'ed object, though it doesn't have column name but I think I can solve it by combining my queries.

```
SELECT TOP 10 OBJECT_NAME (referencing_id) Referencing_Obj, '--->' [uses],
       referenced_Server_name,
       referenced_database_name, 
       referenced_schema_name, 
       referenced_entity_name, 
       '???'  referenced_column_name
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) = 'sp_My_sp'
```

Comment: by db objects you mean queries like procedures etc? so your input is a column name and u want to find where it is used, is it?

Comment: You shouldn't be using sys.sql_dependencies in the first place. It is deprecated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 I think you are looking for remote dependencies? Meaning Procedure1 on DatabaseA references TableB on DatabaseB and you want to find those. Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757387/getting-sql-server-cross-database-dependencies

Comment: Thanks all,  i put updates for my setup and task for clarification . and looks like got good lead using   `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`. Hope it's not depreciated itself?)

Comment: @Sean Tx much, you link is another complete solution. Best all! M

Comment: even this solution doesn't work on column level, only object.  This couldbe ok for my case.

Comment: @Sean and all.  I think for now the only way to get details on column list is to use :

Comment: SELECT referenced_class_desc AS COL_NAME FROM  HEDIS.sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.'+ @objName2, +'object')

Comment: All other solution described in linked materials, doesn't populate it, even they used getTableColumnIds.  You can't get details from  dbA.sys.Objects about   dbBBB table / column.

Comment: You should add that as an answer. Yes it is ok to post an answer to your own question. Then mark is as the solution. That way in the future other people who might be struggling with this have a good solution.