# SQL Server : get INTER db object dependencies of COLUMN Level. This is the only way (** Column Level)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Just want to share my finding after extensive research: Subject was :

How to get dependencies between **DIFFERENT** db objects on **COLUMN** Level?

I was researching this subject for last week and finishing talking to one  W guy who works in SQL group. I'm sure now that using `dm_sql_referenced_entities` the only way to get it in single pass, though you need to feed object name into this dynamic view/table.  All other listed solution works ok but they work only on object level or Column level but within same database, this is b'z SYS tables are dbname specific. (some of these examples are here [Click link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757387/getting-sql-server-cross-database-dependencies).

This is handy but you need to loop it into your object name list. This is exactly how right click on SSMS/view dependency works for given object. There is also the way to do it for linked servers if needed.

```
DECLARE @objName VARCHAR(100)= 'sp_MySP_NAME'  

SELECT TOP 10    
    @objname objName,
    (SELECT DB_NAME()) dbName, 
    '-->' [_],
    referenced_database_name,
    referenced_schema_name,
    referenced_entity_name ObjName, 
    referenced_minor_name ColName,
    referenced_class_desc, 
    is_select_all                     
FROM  
    yourDB.sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.'+ @objName, +'object') a
```