# Running the following query to view a list of all tables and views that are feeding into my Store Procedure, but only pulling from selected database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm fairly new to SQL, and I'm trying to automate my process of viewing all of the tables (from multiple databases) that feed into a specific proc. When I run the below query, I am only getting results from one database, but I know that this SP pulls from 3+ databases. Any suggestions or entirely new ways of going about this?

```
SELECT   
NAME as 'List Of Tables'  
FROM SYSOBJECTS  
WHERE ID IN (   SELECT SD.DEPID   
                FROM SYSOBJECTS SO,   
                SYSDEPENDS SD  
                WHERE SO.NAME = 'X-Table-Name'    
                AND SD.ID = SO.ID  
            )
```

Comment: `sysobjects` (which is a compatibility view, and you should be using `sys.objects`) is database specific. The method you have won't work for getting cross database dependancies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting SQL Server Cross database Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757387/getting-sql-server-cross-database-dependencies)

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you very much for this @Larnu, I just pulled up that page and I'm looking through it now!